# How to surround a callback invocation with another piece of code in a best way?

Tags: java, asynchronous, javafx, callback, java-8

I have a simple, functional interface:

```
public interface Callback<T> {
    void invoke(T param);
}
```

I make many asynchronous operations like:

```
public void getSubfolders(Folder folder, Callback<FolderList> result){
    asyncExecutor.submit(() -> {
        FolderList list = folder.get_SubFolders();
        result.invoke(list);
    });
}
```

The results must be processed on a `main thread`. For that, I have a `JavaFX` method:

`Platform.runLater(Runnable task);`

Which makes my code a mess like this one (and this pattern is repeated in 50 other methods):

```
public void getSubfolders(Folder folder, Callback<FolderList> result){
     asyncExecutor.submit(() -> {
         FolderList list = folder.get_SubFolders();
         Platform.runLater(() -> result.invoke(list));
     });
}
```

I'd like to wrap each callback invocation with `Platform.runLater(...)`.
The only thing I came up with is a `default method`:

```
public interface Callback<T> {
    void invoke(T param);

    default void invokeOnMain(T param){
        Platform.runLater(() -> invoke(param));
    }
}
```

And then, I just call `result.invokeOnMain(list)`.

Is there a better approach for patterns like this one?

Answer (score 3):

You can go one step further than the suggestions in the other answers, and abstract `Platform.runLater()` as an `java.util.concurrent.Executor` (it is, after all, something that executes `Runnable`s).

So you can do this:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executor ;
import java.util.function.Consumer ;
import java.util.function.Supplier ;

public class Invoker {

    private final Executor backgroundExecutor ;
    private final Executor foregroundExecutor ;

    public Invoker(Executor backgroundExecutor, Executor foregroundExecutor) {
        this.backgroundExecutor = backgroundExecutor ;
        this.foregroundExecutor = foregroundExecutor ;
    }

    public <T> void invoke(Supplier<? extends T> task, Consumer<? super T> callback) {
        backgroundExecutor.execute(() -> {
            T result = task.get();
            foregroundExecutor.execute(() -> callback.accept(result));
        });
    }
}
```

And now your example code becomes:

```
Invoker invoker = new Invoker(asyncExecutor, Platform::runLater);
// ...

invoker.invoke(folder::getSubFolders, result::invoke);
```

The nice thing here is you can use the same `Invoker` class with Swing: just create a

```
new Invoker(asyncExecutor, SwingUtilities::invokeLater)
```

[Note: I did not come up with this myself; I saw it in a post on here a few years back. I cannot find that post now to give proper credit, but will edit this if I manage to dig it out. If the person who originally posted this idea sees this, please comment and I will credit you]

Answer (score 2):

It defeats in a some way the [default method intention](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) :

> Default methods enable you to add new functionality to the interfaces
>   of your libraries and ensure binary compatibility with code written
>   for older versions of those interfaces.

Why not put this code in a specific class :

```
public class PlatformUtil {
   public static <T> void invoke(Callback<T> result, T param){
     Platform.runLater(() -> result.invoke(param));
   }
}
```

And from the client side, you could also use a `static import` for `PlatformUtil.invoke` to reduce further the boiler plate code.

It could give :

```
import static PlatformUtil.invoke;
...
public void getSubfolders(Folder folder, Callback<FolderList> result){
     asyncExecutor.submit(() -> {
         FolderList list = folder.get_SubFolders();
         invoke(result, list);
     });
}
```

Of course you could do the same thing with an instance method.

Comment: Just a (off-topic) note that the text you quoted from Oracle is not a true statement. Adding a default method to an existing interface does not *ensure* binary compatibility: there are cases in which it can break existing compiled code. (Specifically, if an existing class implements the interface in question, and also implements another interface that already defines a default method with the same signature, you will break that class by adding the default method to your interface.)

Comment: You are right. It should be mentioned. Now, to be fair, in terms of probability, it should be really uncommon.

Answer (score 1):

After you use the [Decorator Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern), you found that you never need to change the `getSubfolders` method at all. and then you can write a well defined layer system, when you put the components into its own package, for example:

```
//                   v--- move the UiCallback into ui package
package com.projectx.ui;

public class UiCallback<T> implements Callback<T> {
     private final Callback<T> target;
     private UiCallback(Callback<T> target){
       this.target = Objects.requireNonNull(target);
     } 

     public void invoke(T param){
         Platform.runLater(() -> target.invoke(param));
     }

     public static <T> Callback<T> runOnMainThread(Callback<T> source){
        return source instanceof UiCallback? source : new UiCallback<>(source);  
     }
}
```

Everything is fine, there is only one place you need to change is where you call the `getSubfolders`, for example:

```
Callback<T> origin = ...

getSubfolders(folder, runOnMainThread(origin));
```

If you found that you need to call `runOnMainThread` many times in your UI module, maybe you lose some domain concepts in your UI layer. you should to extract new domain concept by new classes or interfaces for that things, e.g: `FolderExplorer`.